# How to initialize members of class/struct type in another class/struct type

Tags: c++, struct, constructor

Assume that I have a struct `foo` and a wrapper struct `wrapper` for `foo` defined below

```
struct foo
{
    int n;
    
    foo(const int s) {n = s};
};

struct wrapper
{
    foo f;
    
    wrapper(const int s);
};
```

Is there a way to use the constructor of `wrapper` to initialize the member of type `foo` in `wrapper` through calling constructor `foo`?

Comment: Look for member initialization.

Comment: Yes, you can. You need to pass the type `foo` in your struct `wrapper` to it recognize, so you can modify the value and do whatever you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want, here foo is initialized with the same `const int` that was given to `wrapper` constructor.

```
struct foo
{
    int n;
    foo(const int s) {n = s;} // <- corrected your typo here
};

struct wrapper
{
    foo f;
    int u;
    wrapper(const int s) : f (s), u(0){  //<- foo initialization here

}

};
```

Comment: What if I have two or more members to be initialized?

Comment: @ZiqiFan I edited the answer to show you how you initialized more members